# Persistence with files in JSF

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, path, relative-path

I'm developing a `JSF` web application, with the current `2.1.7 JSF version`.

Actually, I have a login page, associated with a session bean,
which calls to a logic class "**PersonCatalog**",
which is responsible for reading a text file `.txt` with the information of the persons, like a database but with files.

The problem is to access the file, 
ever I get a NullException because the program doesn't finds the file.
I'm not sure about the path I choose, here is the directory herarchy:

Application

```
 |-- build
 |-- src
       |--eci
           |--pdsw2012
               |--shoeople
                   |--beans
                       |--loginBean and others ...
                   |--logic
                       |--PersonCatalog and others...
                   |--persistence
                       |--files
                           |--persons.txt
 |-- WebContent
       |--WEB-INF
       |--META-INF
       |--a lot of xhtml pages ...
```

I'm using in PersonCatalog for read the **person.txt** file the follow code:

```
File readFile = new File(new String("src/eci/pdsw2012/shoeople/persistence/files/persons.txt"));
```

But I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at eci.pdsw2012.shoeople.logic.PersonCatalog.loadFile(PersonCatalog.java:31)
```

I have used the `ExternalContext().getRealPath()`, but it only shows inside Web-content folder.

I'm using **Eclipse**, and the default route is the installation folder of Eclipse, the is so strange:

```
String ruta = System.getProperty("user.dir");
System.out.println("DirAbs: " + ruta.getAbsolutePath());
```

and prints

```
 C:/Eclipse/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of a deployed web application in this case would be the `WebContent` folder, which contains `WEB-INF`.

In the deployed version the src files are compiled into class files and placed in the following folder `classes`.

The path to persons.txt will be `\WEB-INF\classes\eci\pdsw2012\shoeople\persistence\files\persons.txt`

Comment: Hey thank you maple, i move it and then it works!! thanks a lot friend

Comment: I have a problem, i dont know how to access that file from a .java file, i am using : ((ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext()).getRealPath("/") + "files/personas.txt"  But it doesnt works, save in another folder, thank you!

Comment: @Creativelair This seems like it may be a different problem.  You should post this as different question.